# error when executing function with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, execute

hi:) i'm a newbie to programming and have an assingment wherein i need to extract data from excel files and import them into sqlite3 via python. i was using some code that looked good to me that i found in an online tutorial. this is what i've used:

```
import sqlite3 
import os

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\julia\OneDrive\Documents\python assignment\2016 data -EU values.xlsx')
df.shape
conn = sqlite3.connect('FinalProjectDatabase.sqlite3')
Malta = conn.cursor()
Malta.execute('''CREATE TABLE MaltaData
           (Country TEXT, City TEXT, AirPollutant TEXT, AirPollutionLevel REAL, 
UnitofAirPollutionLevel TEXT, AirQualityStationType TEXT, AirQualityStationArea TEXT, Longitude REAL, 
Latitude REAL, Altitude REAL)'''.format(','.join(df.columns)))

for row in df.iterrows():
    sql = 'INSERT INTO MaltaData (Country TEXT, City TEXT, AirPollutant TEXT, AirPollutionLevel REAL, 
             UnitofAirPollutionLevel TEXT, AirQualityStationType TEXT, AirQualityStationArea TEXT, 
    Longitude REAL, Latitude REAL, Altitude REAL) VALUES (?)*len(df.columns))'
Malta.execute(sql, tuple(row[1]))
conn.commit()
```

my issue arises in the second to last line of code, where ' Malta.execute(sql, tuple(row[1]))' as I keep getting the following syntax error:
Malta.execute(sql, tuple(row[1]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TEXT": syntax error.
I'm not really sure what the second argument means in that execute function, however, the documentation as well as all other sites include it in their code, so i've included it in mine. therefore, i know it needs to be there so i dont know why i keep getting this error.

any help would be greatly appreciated! again, im a newbie, so apologies if this is a silly question

Comment: Remove the data types after all the column names in INSERT statement.

Comment: @forpas thanks for the advice! i've done that, but now i'm getting another error. this is what it says:  Malta.execute(sql, tuple(row[1]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "*": syntax error

Comment: Remove `*len(df.columns)` and write as many `?` as the values that you want to insert inside the parentheses separated by `,`.

Comment: @forpas thanks! it worked:)